# Multiple Authors on Single Post

Tags: capabilities, permissions, multi-author

Does anyone know how to assign multiple Users as authors of single individual posts (even single custom post types)? I want more than just displaying as tags the list of authors.

I am looking at the plugin Groups and do not know if you can set the Author of a post to be a group. Has anyone used this setup before?

I need roles and permissions in place where Users of a Group have EDIT capabilities for a single post. ie. assign Users to a Group; assign a Group to a Post.

Thanks,
Harry

**EDIT(s):**

1) As suggested in the comments I tried out *Co-Authors*, but I found it to be too hard to work with programmatically (poor documentation). I could not accomplish a simple task of adding and removing users programmatically to the author list of a post. I have not gone with this plugin as my solution.

2) See answer about Press Permit. I haven't installed this and tried it out yet, but judging from the video and documentation, it seems that this plugin could be a good solution.

Comment: The Co-Authors Plus plugin allows you to add multiple authors (and guest authors) per post - I'm not sure if that ticks all of your boxes though.

Comment: Thanks! I've looked into Co-Authors plugin and it looks like it will check all my boxes. Awesome find! I think I will have to write some custom functions that will programatically add and remove authors to specific posts. I'll update this question when I get to the implementation.

Comment: I want same functionality is that working for you..??

Comment: I tried Co-Authors. It does allow multiple people to edit and own a single post (or custom post type). I had problems controlling this functionality with code. I couldn't programmatically invoke any of the Co-Authors features. If you are fine using the admin interface, and using the plugin's GUI then this is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I want to throw this out there as an answer to the question. I have stumbled across a plugin that will take WordPress's permissions to the next level.

It is called Press Permit. http://presspermit.com/extensions/pp-collaborative-editing/

Taken from Press Permit FAQ's:

> **How does Press Permit compare to Capability Manager, User Role Editor and other role editor plugins?**
>
> Press Permit’s functionality is different from and complementary to a
>   basic role editor / user management plugin.  In terms of permissions,
>   those plugins’ primary function is to alter WordPress’ definition of
>   the capabilities included in each role.  In other words, they expose
>   lots of knobs for the permissions control which WordPress innately
>   supports. That’s a valuable task, and in many cases will be all the
>   role customization you need.  Since WP role definitions are stored in
>   the main WordPress database, they remain even said plugin is
>   deactivated.
>
> Press Permit can assist you in turning the site-wide capability knobs
>   for desired post types. But it also supercharges your permissions
>   engine. **Press Permit it is particularly useful when you want to
>   customize access to a specific post, category or term.** Extension
>   plugins add collaborative editing control, file filtering and other
>   features which are not otherwise possible. The plugin will work with
>   your WP roles as a starting point, whether customized by a role editor
>   or not.  Users of the PP Collaborative Editing extension can (after
>   activating advanced settings) navigate to Permissions > Settings >
>   Role Usage to see (or modify) how Press Permit is using your WP role
>   definitions. Press Permit’s modifications remain only while it stays
>   active.

It looks like Press Permit's extension Collaborative Editing can accomplish restricting single posts to multiple authors or even groups.

This video explains more about the plugin.

[Allow Editing of Specific WordPress Pages - Press Permit](https://youtu.be/0yOEBD8VE9c?list=PLyelWaWwt1HxuwrZDRBO_c70Tm8A7lfb3)